# Does any of the command line parsing libraries for C++ allow options with N arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am porting a python script to C++ and have not found a way to express an argument such as:

```
--metadata KEY VALUE
```

In the C++ argument parsing libraries I've seen:

- boost::program_options
- TCLAP
- Gflags

Maybe it exists as a possibility in one of those, maybe I have to explore others, maybe I just have to do this by hand.

Do you know of a C++ command line option parsing library that supports multiple arguments for options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line flags which take more than one argument are discouraged by the standard shell utilities syntax guidelines. So I doubt whether you will find a standard library which handles it. It's more common to accept options in the format, for example:

```
--metadata KEY=VALUE
```

and you'll probably find standard libraries which will help you with that format (of course, `strtok` or `std::string::find` are straightforward to use, too).

If you really insist on the multiple-option argument design choice, you can do it with `getopt_long` if you tell it not to permute arguments (put a `+` as the first character of `optstring`); all you need to do is to manually increment `optind` as you read the arguments. (That is: the first argument will be in `optarg`, the next one at `argv[optind++]` and so on.) There are probably equivalent low-level hacks in the C++ libraries, too.

Comment: Actually, this makes more sense and also means any of the libraries will work.